# Run loop every millisecond with sleep_for

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to run a loop inside a thread that calculates some data every millisecond. But I am having trouble with the sleep function. It is sleeping much too long.

I created a basic console application in visual studio:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;
typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int iIdx = 0;
    bool bRun = true;

    auto aTimeStart = Clock::now();

    while (bRun){
        iIdx++;
        if (iIdx >= 500) bRun = false;

        //Sleep(1);
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::microseconds(10));
    }

    printf("Duration: %i ms\n", chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(Clock::now() - aTimeStart).count());

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

This prints out: **Duration: 5000 ms**
The same result is printed, when i use Sleep(1);

I would expect the duration to be **500 ms**, and not 5000 ms. What am I doing wrong here?

**Update:**

---

I was using Visual Studio 2013. Now I have installed Visual Studio 2015, and its fine - prints out: Duration: 500 ms (sometimes its 527 ms).

However, this sleep_for still isn't very accurate, so I will look out for other solutions.

Comment: The C++ standard clocks depend very much on the underlying clocks of the operating system, maybe Windows doesn't have such a high-resolution clock?

Comment: Works on my machine™. What version of Visual Studio are you using? `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` did not have great resolution prior to VS2015. Boost has a pretty much drop in replacement that you can try using in Boost.Chrono

Comment: Also you are performing operation under while loop which will take some amount of cycles. Just to check if you modify iIdx++ to ++iIdx does that make any difference in output ?

Comment: Possibly [`sleep_until`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until) works better in this situation.

Comment: @Jongware sorry, I was remembering incorrectly. With VS2015, `sleep_for` is implemented in terms of `sleep_until`, and basically does `sleep_until(system_clock::now() + duration)` - but system_clock and high_resolution_clock have different epochs. So sleep_until only works with system_clock, not with steady_cock/high_resolution_clock.

Comment: In VS versions prior to VS2015, std::chrono::high_resolution_clock runs at the ticker rate, which by default is 64hz or 15.625 ms. As commented below, timeBeginPeriod can set this to 1ms, although in Windows XP, it changes the tick rate to 1024hz, and there are three double period ticks every 128 tick, so that 128 internal ticks at 1024hz correspond to 125 "user" ticks at 1000hz. For a 1 ms or multiple of 1 ms interval, you might consider using timeSetEvent from  [multimedia timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743612(v=vs.85).aspx),

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The typical time slice used by popular OSs is much longer than 1ms (say 20ms or so); the `sleep` sets a minimum for how long you want your thread to be suspended not a maximum. Once your thread becomes runnable it is up to the OS when to next schedule it.

If you need this level of accuracy you either need a real time OS, or set a very high priority on your thread (so it can pre-empt almost anything else), or write your code in the kernel, or use a busy wait.

But do you really need to do the calculation every ms? That sort of timing requirement normally comes from hardware. What goes wrong if you bunch up the calculations a bit later?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, try `timeBeginPeriod`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757624(v=vs.85).aspx
It increases timer resolution.

Comment: On VS2015, `high_resolution_clock` uses the performance counter, which is not affected by this.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong here?

Attempting to use `sleep` for precise timing.

`sleep(n)` does not pause your thread for precisely `n` time then immediately continue.

`sleep(n)` yields control of the thread back to the scheduler, and indicates that you do not want control back until *at least* `n` time has passed.

Now, the scheduler already divvies up thread processing time into *time slices*, and these are typically on the order of 25 milliseconds or so. That's the *bare minimum* you can expect your sleep to run.

`sleep` is simply the wrong tool for this job. *Never* use it for precise scheduling.

Answer (score 0):

This thread is fairly old, but perhaps someone can still use this code.

It's written for C++11 and I've tested it on Ubuntu 15.04.

```
class MillisecondPerLoop
  {
  public:
    void do_loop(uint32_t loops)
      {
      int32_t time_to_wait = 0;
      next_clock = ((get_current_clock_ns() / one_ms_in_ns) * one_ms_in_ns);
      for (uint32_t loop = 0; loop < loops; ++loop)
        {
        on_tick();

        // Assume on_tick takes less than 1 ms to run

        // calculate the next tick time and time to wait from now until that time
        time_to_wait = calc_time_to_wait();

        // check if we're already past the 1ms time interval
        if (time_to_wait > 0)
          {
          // wait that many ns
          std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::nanoseconds(time_to_wait));
          }
        ++m_tick;
      }
    }

 private:
   void on_tick()
     {
     // TEST only: simulate the work done in every tick
     // by waiting a random amount of time
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(distribution(generator)));
     }

   uint32_t get_current_clock_ns()
     {
     return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(
     std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
     }

   int32_t calc_time_to_wait()
     {
     next_clock += one_ms_in_ns;
     return next_clock - get_current_clock_ns();
     }

   static constexpr uint32_t one_ms_in_ns = 1000000L;

   uint32_t m_tick;
   uint32_t next_clock;
 };
```

A typical run shows a pretty accurate 1ms loop with a 1- 3 microsecond error. Your PC may be more accurate than this if it's a faster CPU.

Here's typical output:

```
One Second Loops:
        Avg (ns)       ms   err(ms)
   [ 0]   999703   0.9997   0.0003
   [ 1]   999888   0.9999   0.0001
   [ 2]   999781   0.9998   0.0002
   [ 3]   999896   0.9999   0.0001
   [ 4]   999772   0.9998   0.0002
   [ 5]   999759   0.9998   0.0002
   [ 6]   999879   0.9999   0.0001
   [ 7]   999915   0.9999   0.0001
   [ 8]  1000043   1.0000  -0.0000
   [ 9]   999675   0.9997   0.0003
   [10]  1000120   1.0001  -0.0001
   [11]   999606   0.9996   0.0004
   [12]   999714   0.9997   0.0003
   [13]  1000171   1.0002  -0.0002
   [14]   999670   0.9997   0.0003
   [15]   999832   0.9998   0.0002
   [16]   999812   0.9998   0.0002
   [17]   999868   0.9999   0.0001
   [18]  1000096   1.0001  -0.0001
   [19]   999665   0.9997   0.0003
Expected total time: 20.0000ms
Actual total time  : 19.9969ms
```

I have a more detailed write up here:
   https://arrizza.org/wiki/index.php/One_Millisecond_Loop